# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder in bitmap casting c#

Tags: c#, casting, bitmap

In order to convert bitmap to base64 i have to convert my bitmap to Image
I get this message when i'm converting an image to memorystream as `img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);` after casting my image from a screenshoot bitmap like `Image img = (Image)bitmap;` or `Image img = bitmap as Image`, but it's working fine when i use local stored image like `Image img = Image.FromFile(Path)`.
how can i avoid this error while i don't want to store the screenshoot and read it again each time
this is the code i have tried

```
  Image img = bitmap as Image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: you should add some code snippets for what you have tried

Comment: `RawFormat` returns the format the image was in when it was loaded. Just specify a _real_ format there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to convert `Bitmab` to `Image` while you can encode your `Bitmab` with `Base64` directly

try this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     bitmab.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // you can change your image format as you want
     byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
     string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
}
```